# Get total of out of stock products, total price added to the inventory records for the user laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, items

So I have this situation where I have an Items table

```
 Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string("name", 255)->index();
        $table->float("price");
        $table->foreignId("business_id")->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->float('selling_price')->after('price');
        $table->bigInteger('quantity_in_stock')->after('price')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('unlimited')->after('quantity_in_stock')->default(false);
        $table->timestamp("last_purchase_date")->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

So I want to return the items of a specific user using the business he created
I want to calculate the total price, total number of products that quantity in stock is zero.
please help

Comment: What you have done so far?

Comment: `Item::where(['business_id' => auth()->user()->business->id])->latest()->get();`
This was what I originally had which fetches all the Items added by the user, I would have just loop over these items to calculate the total stock using the price of the items but I'm thinking of performance when the items reach 5000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DB::table('itmes')
         ->select('business_id',DB::raw('count(*) as total_number, sum('price') as total_price'))
         ->where('quantity_in_stock', 0)
         ->groupBy('business_id')
         ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, but a user can have so many records